# 3-way light circuit to an outbuilding with a disconnect

Tags: electrical

US, Southern CA, NEC 2017

I'm hoping to run power from a house to a new backyard shed and I'd like to be able to control the lights from both the shed and the house, but I'm not sure if I'd run afoul of the circuit-limitations for an outbuilding. For this use case adding a subpanel at the shed isn't an option, and both circuits are 120v. Hardwired solutions (no wireless switches) preferred.

### Questions

- Is there an acceptable method to control a light at an outbuilding using a 3-way circuit, with one switch inside the outbuilding, and one at the feed point?
- Since there needs to be a disconnect means at the outbuilding, what could be used to satisfy this requirement?

Comment: Do single circuits even need a disconnecting means at the outbuilding?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I think the relevant code is NEC 225.31 and 225.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're allowed to run a switch spur back to the main building

The good news is that you are permitted by NEC 225.30 to run a 3-way switch spur (two travelers and a hot or switched-hot) back to the main building from the outbuilding, although that takes up the single circuit the Code allows you to run back in this situation.  I would run it in a separate conduit, though, to avoid hitting derates due to having more than three current-carrying conductors in a single conduit if you decide to pull a feeder through the main conduit to the outbuilding.

### As to that disconnecting means

While you could use an ordinary or key-operated lightswitch as the outbuilding disconnect for a single branch circuit, I tend to prefer non-fused *pullout disconnects* of the type commonly used for air conditioner disconnecting service for this job.  They can handle both single-circuit and multi-wire branch circuit situations, are weatherproof (NEMA 3R) by default, and quite inexpensive for what you get.  They're also *distinctive* in that you won't mix them up for a lightswitch when you're working in the shed!

### If you really want a diagram...

If you really want a diagram of this all, I edited the diagram from your deleted question to depict what I'm talking about, as shown below.  Note that the travelers and switched-hot all pass through the disconnect without being switched by it, since they are powered from an always-hot feed that's already subject to that disconnect.  Note also that especially with an AC disconnect, you'll need to be careful to land your equipment *ground* on the disconnect's bonded, while your feeder *neutral* does *not* stop at the disconnect at all; instead, it is simply spliced or pulled through.

[image: edited diagram]

Comment: I believe I need a disconnect means for all three hot wires: the un-switched hot and the two travelers, is that correct? If so, is there a single device that would serve that purpose? Or do the two need separate disconnects?

Comment: @CJC -- if they're fed from downstream of the outbuilding disconnecting means, then they don't need disconnects of their own!

Comment: @CJC -- no, the disconnecting means has to be at the outbuilding, *but* what you're missing is that if always-hot for the switch circuit is fed from a source that's turned off by that disconnecting means, then the travelers and switched-hot for that circuit don't need to be switched *again* by the outbuilding disconnecting means since power's already been cut off to that part of the circuit